# Xkb: Overlay vs HotKeys

Tags: xkb

I'm configured xkb to select each keyboard layouts with unique hotkey (en = Win+1, de = Win+2, jp = Win+3)

```
replace key <I156> { [NoSymbol], actions[Group1] = [ LockGroup(group=1) ] };
replace key <I157> { [NoSymbol], actions[Group1] = [ LockGroup(group=2) ] };
replace key <I210> { [NoSymbol], actions[Group1] = [ LockGroup(group=3) ] };

replace key <LWIN> {
    symbols[Group1] = [ Super_L ],
    actions[Group1] = [ SetControls(controls=overlay1)  ]
};

key <AE01> { overlay1 = <I156> };
key <AE02> { overlay1 = <I157> };
key <AE03> { overlay1 = <I210> };
```

But it breaks hotkeys with Win key (e.g. Win + T). Is it possible to configure key to switch overlay that does not break hotkeys?